# cin not allowing input after first use of function

Tags: c++

Completely new to c++ or any sort of programming for that matter. 
I am trying to do a simple input/output, however im not given the chance to enter my second input after answering the first question.

I have tried looking things up online. But given the fact that this (supposedly haha) an extremley easy code, no one has had this same issue....which brings me here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    string question1;

    question1 = "are you studying right now? " ;

    cout << question1 << endl;

    char ans1;

    cin >> ans1;

    string question2;

    question2 = "okay, how long will you be studying for? ";

    cout << question2 << endl;

    char ans2;

    cin >> ans2;
}
```

So again, im able to answer the first question. However, once I answer the first question the computer gives me the question, but this time it will not let me answer it.

Comment: Start a good habit now: do not dump the namespace via `using namespace std;`. Instead, write `std::cout`, `std::cin`, `std::endl` and `std::string`. (If you prefer the short forms, there is a way to get them without dumping the namespace, but for now, I would recommend that you write the symbols out in full.)

Comment: This program compiles and runs for me fine. https://repl.it/repls/CluelessImaginaryAddition

Comment: I actually starting doing that in the beggining, however my professor told the class to start using "using namespace std; ". but okayI will start writing them in individually again

Comment: @Fooji You should probably do as your instructor says _but_ just remember that this is discouraged in the real world, so when you're out of school stop doing it again :P Sadly you will find a lot of misteachings like this.

Comment: real shell? sorry I have no idea what that program is. My professor wanted us to use ubuntu or apple terminal only. kinda rediculus as I only had a windows pc. had to partition my pc to install ubuntu.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit okay I will definitely stop using "using namespace std; " Don't want to start a bad habit. Especially this early into programming.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `char` type only contain **one** character. You must use `string` to contain more than one word.
2. The problem may occur by `cin`, since the `cin` contains `\n` after you enter some word. It's related to the buffer problem. I suggest you to use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) for the problem.

Comment: `>>` discards whitespace such as line breaks so they shouldn't cause a problem here.

Comment: @FeiXiang I found the similar problem here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks a lot man. I'm already learning more here than in class haha

Comment: @Fooji Glad to help you :)

Comment: @박주언 That post is not entirely correct. `>>` leaves line breaks in the stream, but it also ignores leading whitespace, which means that if you only use `>>`, you shouldn't get empty inputs because of this (you can try it yourself). Meanwhile, `getline()` doesn't ignore leading whitespace, so mixing it with `>>` can cause problems. The OP is only using `>>` here, so it's fine.